# Typo3 6.2: Table Records in FCE (Flux)

Tags: typo3, flux

I am trying to get a list of table-records in my FCE.
In documentation, i found the part "items" can use a Query.
But i can not find a way to make it work.

```
    <flux:field.select name="myRecord" items="NOTHING WORKS HERE" label="Choose" maxItems="1" minItems="1" size="5" multiple="false" />
```

Does anybody know how the items can be filled with table-records ?

Comment: Did you found a solution for it? I need this too

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the select box with all items maybe you can then switch to this:

```
<flux:field.relation size="1" minItems="0" table="tx_{YourExtensionName}_domain_model_{YourObjectName}" maxItems="1" name="package">
</flux:field.relation>
```

Of course, you can use any table from the DB, like "pages"..

Hope it helps!